# What is happening when attributes are applied to a class method in python?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been learning python and django and building a simple blog as a test.

I have Django admin running and working fine, and was trying to modify the admin classes to introduce an image thumbnail into the list view.

Using the example in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), I have got the thumbnail working using the following in my admin class:

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('thumbnail', "name", "created")


def thumbnail(self, image):
    return '<img src="%s" alt="%s" width="100px" />' % (image.url, image.name)
thumbnail.short_description = "Thumbnail"
thumbnail.allow_tags = True
thumbnail.admin_order_field = "name"
```

It all works just fine, but I don't understand fully what the method definition for `ImageAdmin.thumbnail` is doing, where it appears to be adding properties to the method. So I was hoping someone could help explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, class methods themselves are objects, and you can set attributes (not, strictly speaking, properties - `property` has a specific meaning in Python) on them. These attributes are then available to anything that can access the method - Django will check `foo.thumbnail.allow_tags` to see if it should escape the results of calling `foo.thumbnail()`.

There are some subtleties - bound instance methods don't allow setting attributes, so you can't actually assign to `foo.thumbnail.allow_tags`. But doing it at the class level works fine.

For a full description, check out [PEP 232](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/).

Comment: perfect - that's exactly the explanation I was looking for, thank you. As soon as I can accept, I will.

Answer (score 0):

The method `thumbnail` is called to display the value. Django allows you to set attributes on it which are used for other purposes, such as the name in the admin (`thumbnail.short_description = "Thumbnail"`). So both the method and the properties that are set on it are used.

Comment: `Django also` => `Django allows` ;)

Comment: I can see that attributes (I should edit my title I guess) are being added to the method, I just don't really understand how. Is this a python thing or is Django adding some functionality to the basic language?

Comment: You can access attributes by doing `getattr(obj, 'name_of_attribute')`. So this is a Python thing and Django uses it heavily. Even when `obj` is a function or a method.

Comment: @PolloFrito, Methods, functions, classes, types are all objects. And as such, in general case, you can set arbitrary attributes to them, like in this case.

Comment: Thanks guys - accepted the other answer it was a more concise answer with a link to docs which really helped.